# child_process working directory

Tags: node.js, bash, child-process, drush

I am trying to execute a child process in a different directory then the one of its parent.

```
var script = "drush language-add cn";
var folderDrush = "/data/www/sites/site_cn_country";
exec(script, {cwd:folderDrush} , function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    if(err) {
        sendErr("drush", stderr);
        sendCommand(script);
        sendCheck("drush", false);
    }
});
```

This script returns:

> The drush command 'language-add cs' could not be found. Run `drush [31;40m[1m[error][0m cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.

But when I execute manualy, drush language-add work fine.

I test there commands too :

> - `pwd : /data/www/sites/site_cn_country`
> - `id -u -n : root`
> - `ll : Command not found (why ? manually work...)`
> - `echo $SHELL : /bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but you could change path before running the command:

```
var script = "cd /data/www/sites/site_cn_country && drush language-add cn";
```

Comment: Same error : The drush command 'language-add cs' could not be found. Run `drush [31;40m[1m[error][0m cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.